$\nu_t=\text{ess sup}_T\frac{E[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s R_s|F_t]}{E[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s|F_t]}$ implies $\text{ess sup}_TE[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)|F_t]=0$?
Let $(R_s)^\infty_{s=1}$ be a bounded process
adapted to a filtration $(\mathscr{F}_s)^\infty_{s=1}$,
let $0 < c < 1$,
and for each integer $t > 0$ let
\begin{equation*}
\nu_t = 
\text{ess sup}_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s R_s|\mathscr{F}_t]}{\mathbb{E}[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s |\mathscr{F}_t]},
\end{equation*}
where $\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}$ is the collection of stopping times $T\geq t+1$.
It then directly follows that $0$ is an essential upper bound of
the collection of random variables
$\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum\limits^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)
|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\Big)_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}$,
that is,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\leq 0
\end{equation*}
almost surely for each $T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}$.
Intuitively, I would also expect $0$ to be an essential lower bound of
the essential upper bounds of
$\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum\limits^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)
|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\Big)_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}$,
i.e., that $0$ is the essential supremum of
$\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum\limits^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)
|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\Big)_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}$,
and that this should follow quite directly from the definition,
but I can't figure out how.
If $U$ is an essential upper bound of
$\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum\limits^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)
|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\Big)_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}$
then for each $T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}$ almost surely
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^sR_s|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]
-
\nu_t
\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]
\leq U,
\end{equation*}
where the left-hand side is almost surely bounded from above by $0$.
But how to show that $0\leq U$ almost surely?
From a 1986 article by Mandelbaum on multi-armed bandits
I know that there is a $T^*\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}$ for which the essential supremum is attained, so that $0$ must be the essential supremum,
but I actually want to use the latter to show the former (and the article doesn't go into that much detail on this).

If $U$ is an essential upper bound of
$\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum\limits^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\Big)_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}$
then for each $T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}$ we have almost surely
\begin{equation*}
\frac{
\mathbb{E}\big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^sR_s|\mathscr{F}_t\big]
}{
\mathbb{E}\big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s   |\mathscr{F}_t\big]
}
-
\nu_t
\leq
\frac{U}{\mathbb{E}\big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s|\mathscr{F}_t\big]}
\leq
c^{-(t+1)}U,
\end{equation*}
hence almost surely
\begin{equation*}
0
=
c^{t+1}
\bigg(
\text{ess sup}_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}
\frac{
\mathbb{E}\big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^sR_s|\mathscr{F}_t\big]
}{
\mathbb{E}\big[\sum^T_{s=t+1}c^s   |\mathscr{F}_t\big]
}
-
\nu_t
\bigg)
\leq
U.
\end{equation*}
It follows that $0$ is an essential lower bound of all essential upper bounds $U$ of
$\Big(\mathbb{E}\Big[\sum\limits^T_{s=t+1}c^s(R_s-\nu_t)|\mathscr{F}_t\Big]\Big)_{T\in\mathfrak{M}_{t+1}}$.
